# When I click cancel on the searchbar it disappears

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UISearchBar, when I click cancel button on the searchbar it disappears. The UITableView is moved on top of the search bar and the search bar disappears underneath. Here's my code:

```
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
    searchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    
    
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: 44)
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
    searchBar.placeholder = " Search book title, author..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchBarView.addSubview(searchBar)
    innerView.addSubview(searchBarView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this happens because searchBar recalculates its frame after Cancel button clicked and gets zero height. Try to move searchBar initialisation logic to separate method and call it also in searchBarCancelButtonClicked method of UISearchBarDelegate.

Also my advice to you: up your deployment target to iOS 11 and instead of manipulations with searchBar just use this:

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```